# Controlling tile radius with ggplot2 geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heatmap using `ggplot2` that controls for two different continuous variables. One only has values greater than 0. For that variable, I would like to control the 'radius' of the tile such that the maximum value is a tile that takes up all available space, and 0 means that the tile will have an area of 0. So far, using `aes(size = ...)` has not given any results, and I feel lost as to what to do.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <-
    data_frame(
        factor_1 = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5)),
        factor_2 = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 5)),
        value_1  = rnorm(25),
        value_2  = runif(25)
    )

ggplot(dat) +
    geom_tile(aes(x = factor_1, y = factor_2, fill = value_1, size = value_2))
```

produces

[image: heatmap]

As we can see, there is a size legend that scales with `value_2`, but the tiles are all uniformly sized.

The result I would like to obtain is similar to the first two examples at this link for the [corrplot function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) where the circles or squares can vary in size, leaving a white border around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `width` and `height` aesthetics:

```
ggplot(dat) +
    geom_tile(aes(x = factor_1, y = factor_2, fill = value_1, 
                  width = value_2, height = value_2))
```

For some reason I get warnings about these being "unknown aesthetics", but they are obviously working to set the width and height of the tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This controls the width and height, but it does not produce a legend. I suppose I could manually fudge one, but I would love an answer where that happens automatically.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380249/adding-a-legend-to-a-ggplot2-geom-tile-plot-based-on-size . Might not be possible with `geom_tile` but you can switch to `geom_point`

Comment: Got it. It does seem to be currently impossible with geom_tile. Controlling width and height seems like a very good work around.